# How to use rewrite in Nginx?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I use .htaccess in Apache2, it works well.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

and now I use nginx rewrite, in sites-available, i make this config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
root /home/domain;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
location / {
    rewrite "^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$" profile.php?username=$1 last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

but it doesn't work, it shows 404 Not Found, can you help me the error? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue with the rewrite translation. Check this updated rewrite translation in this code.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
root /home/domain;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1;
}
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, can you explain why here should use `if (!-e $request_filename){`, in .htaccess, it use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.